# How do I get a 3 dimension velocity vector from a speed and 3 dimension angle vector

Tags: lua, game-physics, roblox

So I have a function called

```
function AngleToVector(speed,xAngle,yAngle,zAngle)

    local angle = Vector3.new(xAngle,yAngle,zAngle)

    --
    -- calculations
    --

    local position = Vector3.new(SOMETHING,SOMETHING,SOMETHING)
    return position

end
```

I decided to rewrite the entire question. In the picture, sqrt(27) is the distance a bullet travels in one second. Assume that I know the 3 angles that dictate where this line is pointing. I'm trying to find the length of the 3, red green and blue, dotted lines using my "speed" scalar, and my 3 angles which show the direction of my scalar.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this just simply vector arithmetic?  Speed * the angle vector will give the steps needed to move at the speed given each step.

Comment: well again, i'm not familiar with whatever branch of mathematics this falls under. I'm guessing it's trigonometry.

Comment: It's not trigonometry, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You state that the final Vector3 that is returned should contain the values that the subject should step in to travel a certain speed.  This is actually quite straight forward.  The returned Vector3 should be the unit vector of the angle vector multiplied by the speed scalar.

This is more of a Math question than a programming question, and I am not familiar with the library you are using, so I will answer it mathematically.  First, divide each component of the angle vector by the magnitude of the angle vector.  This gives you a unit vector in that direction (e.g. 1 meter in that direction).  Multiply this unit vector by the speed given, and that will give you `speed` steps in that direction.  You can then add this new vector to the current position for the object to move.

I recommend doing some reading on Vectors and Matrices.

Comment: I'm not sure if that answers my question. I have rewrote the entire question so it's more clear, and remade the picture.

Comment: The answer I've given is still correct.  The resulting Vector3 will contain the values you need to step in each direction.  What don't you understand?  Help me to help you.

Comment: Just realised that you might be using a Vector3 to store the actual angles in degrees/radians, and that the Vector3 is not actually a Vector at all.  Is this the case?

Comment: yes, they are just used to hold rotation angles. Like if a cube is rotated in 3d space with the angles (45 degrees on the x-axis,90 degrees on the y-axis,15 degrees on the z-axis). A line will be drawn with a given length starting at the center of the cube, and parallel to the edges of the cube.

So yes, they are not vector angles, whatever those are.

Comment: Ahh.  That's very misleading.  The angles you are storing, where do they come from?

Comment: A Cube that is rotated on it's 3 axis

Comment: You might need to take your question to Math.

Answer (score 0):

`velocityVector = CFrame.Angles(xAngle,yAngle,zAngle).lookVector*speed`

Is probably what you want. `CFrame.lookVector` gives you the unit Vector that Luke was talking about. [CFrame](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=CFrame#Properties) makes everything a ton easier when you get used to it.

Comment: It seems you are familiar with Roblox, and not somone who just arrived here because of the LUA tag. If you are and you ever heard of a game on Roblox called Armored Patrol where all the bullets have anchored parts, and the physics for them is calculated using a script the creator made. That's basically what I'm doing. The way i'm doing is that you will start with 3 angles and a speed, and i want to convert that to 3 values that represent the speed doing up/down left/right back/forth. I can't test this out atm, but ill get to it and see if it works.